# Jekyll: Translate month in date functions

Tags: internationalization, jekyll

I'm trying to get Jekyll to acknowledge german month names. I installed the i18n_filter.rb plugin and added a german locale to my project.

When I try

```
{{ site.posts.first.date | localize: "%d.%B %Y" }}
```

It returns `21.n 2013`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the german locale file here?

Comment: @Ameer https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/de.yml

Answer (score 1):

You must change the locale in the `i18n_filter.rb` plugin in line 3.

Like this:

```
LOCALE = :ge # set your locale
```